# Ajax load php file into div

Tags: php, jquery

Hy I have dynamic div the Containing search result, I im tring to code that if one of the div is clicked than load php file into some div.
the problem that I can't figure out how to do that with send a POST/GET request.

this is the search result:

```
<div id="srcfrd">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" id="friendid" value="1" hidden>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="srcfrd">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" id="friendid" value="2" hidden>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="srcfrd">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" id="friendid" value="3" hidden>
    <br/>
</div>
```

now, onclick on one of the divs it should load a php file in another div.
the php file should print the friend details according to the POST/GET id request.

this is my js (its is load the php but i need to add the id value to show the correct user)

```
    $('#srcfrd').click(function() {
    $.get('showfriend.php', function(data) {
        $('#middelfeedbody').html(data);
    });
});
```

and here I am stuck

```
    $('#srcfrd').click(function() {

    var idvalue = ??

    $.get('showfriend.php?id="+idvalue+"', function(data) {
        $('#middelfeedbody').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: why all your divs have the same id?

Comment: You can't duplicate ID attributes in HTML, doing it will potentially create unexpected results and/or stop your jQuery from working (as it's a DOM traversal wrapper, it relies on having valid syntax). **Edit:** [use classes](http://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to add a hidden field to store the user's id in the dom.

```
// Wrong
<input type="text" id="friendid" value="1" hidden>

// Good
<input type="hidden" name="friendid" value="1">
```

You can also save your user's ID in the dom using [**data** attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Another way is to store the user's id as the `ID` of your div in order to have a unique ID then a class called `user` for styling and javascript.

```
<div class="user" id="user-1">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" name="friendid" value="1" hidden>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user-2">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" name="friendid" value="2" hidden>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user-3">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg'>
    <span class="name"><h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4></span>
    <input type="text" name="friendid" value="3" hidden>
<br>
</div>
```

Then in javascript we will bind the event to every occurence of `user` class.

```
$(function(){

    $('.user').click(function(){

        // Retrieve the id from the hidden field.
        var id_value = $(this).find('input[name="friendid"]').val();

        // Retreive the user's ID from the ID attribute
        // var id_value = this.id.substring(5); // let's get rid of the prefix

        // if you're using a data attribute
        // may be data-user
        // then we'll use this instead
        // var id_value = $(this).data('user');

        $.get('showfriend.php', {id: id_value}, function(data) {
            $('#middelfeedbody').html(data);
        });

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending "idvalue" instead of your variable. Try with:

```
$('#srcfrd').click(function() {

var idvalue = ??

$.get('showfriend.php?id='+idvalue, function(data) {
    $('#middelfeedbody').html(data);
});
```

});